# Change NaN values according to consensus values in another column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I need to change some NaN values according to consensus values in another colomn, so here is the exemple:

tab1

```
col1    col2    col3
seq1    NaN     SeqA
seq2    group1  SeqA
seq3    group1  SeqA
seq4    NaN     SeqA
seq5    group2  SeqB
seq6    NaN     SeqB
seq7    NaN     SeqB
seq8    NaN     SeqC
seq9    group3  SeqC
seq10   group3  SeqC
seq11   group4  SeqC
seq12   group5  SeqD
seq13   group6  SeqD
seq14   NaN     SeqD 
seq15   group7  NaN
seq16   group7  NaN
```

and the idea is to change it as:

```
col1    col2    col3
seq1    group1  SeqA
seq2    group1  SeqA
seq3    group1  SeqA
seq4    group1  SeqA
seq5    group2  SeqB
seq6    group2  SeqB
seq7    group2  SeqB
seq8    group3  SeqC
seq9    group3  SeqC
seq10   group3  SeqC
seq11   group4  SeqC
seq12   group5  SeqD
seq13   group6  SeqD
seq14   NaN     SeqD
```

- As you can see the `seqs 1` and `4` were changed to `group1` in `col2` because two same `SeqA` where in this group.
- As you can see the `seqs 6` and `7` were changed to `group2` in `col2` because one same `SeqB` was in this group.
- As you can see the `seq 8` was changed to `group3` in `col2` because two same `SeqC` where in this group against only one in the g`roup4`.
- As you can see the `seq 14` is still a `NaN` because there was none consensus in `col2` for `SeqD`.

Does anyone have an idea to do it with pandas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "consensus"? It seems to me you mean the mode, i.e. the value that appears the most often.  Have you looked into https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function for avoid replace `NaN`s in last case:

```
def f(x):
    c = x['col2'].value_counts()
    if c.empty:
        return x
    elif (len(c) == 1) or (c.nunique() != 1):
        x['col2'] = x['col2'].fillna(c.index[0])
    return x

df = df.groupby('col3').apply(f)
print (df)
     col1    col2  col3
0    seq1  group1  SeqA
1    seq2  group1  SeqA
2    seq3  group1  SeqA
3    seq4  group1  SeqA
4    seq5  group2  SeqB
5    seq6  group2  SeqB
6    seq7  group2  SeqB
7    seq8  group3  SeqC
8    seq9  group3  SeqC
9   seq10  group3  SeqC
10  seq11  group4  SeqC
11  seq12  group5  SeqD
12  seq13  group6  SeqD
13  seq14     NaN  SeqD
```

Comment: @chippycentra - ya, give me some time for find solution

Answer (score 4):

Try below code:

`df.groupby('col3')['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))`

As rightly pointed out by @jezrael, last value should be NaN because of non - consensus:

```
def func(x):
     if len(x.value_counts()) ==1:
             return x.fillna(x.mode()[0])
     elif x.value_counts()[0] != x.value_counts()[1]:
             return x.fillna(x.mode()[0])
     else:
             return x

df.groupby('col3')['col2'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```